# SharePoint 2013: Re-sort or Hide Grouping Row in Gantt View

Tags: 2013, gantt-view

I have a user who is using a SharePoint list with a gantt view as MS Project-lite. For each Project, there are 4 entries in the list:  Project, Phase 1, Phase 2, Phase 3. Each entry has a reference to the master project information (in another list), a start date, and end date. The gantt view is grouped by project and each group is sorted by start date (e.g. Project 1 starts before Project 2). Our gantt rows currently look like this:

Project:  Project 1
      Project 1
      Phase 1
      Phase 2
      Phase 3

Project:  Project 2
      Project 2
      Phase 1
      Phase 2
      Phase 3

My user wants to have certain "promoted" projects that are sorted to the top, regardless of start date.  I have created a field for this, but for some reason the gantt view won't promote them even when I have this as my primary sort (e.g. Promoted = yes)

I can group on Promoted Yes/No to achieve the sorting I want, but don't want this grouping row to show as it wastes valuable real estate on the page:

<s>Promoted: Yes</s>

  Project:  Project 2
       Project 2
       Phase 1
       Phase 2
       Phase 3

<s>Promoted: No</s>

  Project:  Project 1
       Project 1
       Phase 1
       Phase 2
       Phase 3

Project:  Project 3
       Project 3
       Phase 1
       Phase 2
       Phase 3

How do I get Project 2 to appear above Project 1 if it's flagged as promoted, without showing the "promoted" grouping?  I can use javascript/jquery in a script web part to achieve this (but don't know the specifics - I'm new to SP scripting), but cannot install custom tools on the server.

Comment: are you tried to sort with promoted Desc, not Asc to show Yes before No

Comment: Yes, that sort doesn't work at all, asc or desc.  Project 2 stays in the middle. 
 I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for, which involves:

1. Creating a calculated field concatenating the Promoted and Project Name fields.  Result is "True:Project 2" or "False: Project 1".
2. Grouping on the calculated field
3. Adding a bit of jquery to hide the "True:" and "False"

I even made it work with my lookup-type fields!

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16827.sharepoint-2010-group-by-view-with-order-by-on-datetime-field.aspx